# Create Linked Server to connect SQL Server 2005 Developer Ed

Tags: sql-server, linked-list

is it possible create a linked server on sql server 2005 Enterprise edition and connect to SQL Server 2005 Developer edition on another server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is Yes.

With sql server 2005 Enterprise edition you get SQL-Server Management Studio (SSMS) and there in the object explorer you find Server Objects | Linked Servers. There you can establish new linked servers.
(I hope the GUI didn't change, as I'm using SQL-Server 2008).